# Can not convert from Japanese text string to NSUTF8StringEncoding

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, encode, cjk

This is the original string:

```
"101","çÇìc éOòY","¿∂¿ﬁªÃﬁ€≥","100",
"102","êÛìc å‹òY","±ª¿ﬁ∫ﬁ€≥","100",
"103","é·ìc ëÂï„","‹∂¿¿ﬁ≤Ωπ","100",
"104","ïêìc ëæòY","¿π¿ﬁ¿€≥","200",
"105","çÇå¥Å@èü","¿∂ ◊œªŸ","200",
"106","è¨ñÏÅ@é¿","µ…–…Ÿ","300",
"107","ê¥êÖÅ@óyçÅ","º–Ωﬁ Ÿ∂","300",
```

This is what I want:

```
"101","高田 三郎","ﾀｶﾀﾞｻﾌﾞﾛｳ","100",
"102","浅田 五郎","ｱｻﾀﾞｺﾞﾛｳ","100",
"103","若田 大輔","ﾜｶﾀﾀﾞｲｽｹ","100",
"104","武田 太郎","ﾀｹﾀﾞﾀﾛｳ","200",
"105","高原　勝","ﾀｶﾊﾗﾏｻﾙ","200",
"106","小野　実","ｵﾉﾐﾉﾙ","300",
"107","清水　遥香","ｼﾐｽﾞﾊﾙｶ","300",
```

I code like this:

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Zaikoichi" ofType:@"txt"];
NSError *error;
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding error:&error];
```

and get a result like this:

```
"101","çÇìc éOòY","¿∂¿ﬁªÃﬁ€≥","100",
"102","êÛìc å‹òY","±ª¿ﬁ∫ﬁ€≥","100",
"103","é·ìc ëÂï„","‹∂¿¿ﬁ≤Ωπ","100",
```

It is return nil when I use this:

```
NSString * content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:&encoding encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

From this txt file I want to get a readable NSString. I tried searching but I did not find a solution.In my case, customers do not modify txt file to UTF8 manual. They just copy file to iCloud document , after that my application read this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by using NSShiftJISStringEncoding

```
NSString * path = [self getIcloudPathFromFileName:name];

NSError *error;
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSShiftJISStringEncoding error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

As the text file is in the bundle and you have access to it open it in a text editor and save it UTF8 encoded.

Then read it always with `NSUTF8StringEncoding` encoding.

Comment: Hi, In my case, customer doesn't open text editor to save UTF8  like this, they just copy txt file to iCloud and my application read this file directly .

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `path` in `stringWithContentsOfFile` and not `&encoding`

```
NSString * content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```